# Gradle cannot find a project in a dependency chain

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

I have 3 Java projects located next to each other in the folder structure: `Proj1`, `Proj2` and `Proj3`. `Proj1` depends on `Proj2` and it depends on `Proj3`.

Here are their `settings.gradle` files:

```
rootProject.name = 'Proj3'
```

---

```
rootProject.name = 'Proj2'

include ':Proj3'
project(':Proj3').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Proj3')
```

---

```
rootProject.name = 'Proj1'

include ':Proj2'
project(':Proj2').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Proj2')
```

and their `gradle.build` files:

For 2

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':Proj3')
}
```

For 1

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':Proj2')
}
```

The 2nd and 3rd projects are built fine by Gradle but when I try to build the 1st it complains that

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':Proj2:'. Project with path ':Proj3' could not be found in project ':Proj2'.

and points to the line `compile project(':Proj3')` (in the build of `Proj2`). Stack trace starts with

> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip'.

Don't know why the 2nd project can find the 3rd fine when it's built and suddenly not when the 1st is built. Why would the 1st care about how the 2nd searches for the 3rd after its already included in the "Project and External Dependencies" folder.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you've maid a wrong project configuration. You can have only one `settings.gradle` file for one multimodule project and this single file should include all modules.

So the structure might be something like this:

```
RootProject/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  Proj1/
    build.gradle
  Proj2/
    build.gradle
  Proj3/
    build.gradle
```

And `settings.gradle` should contains atleast follows:

```
include 'Proj1', 'Proj2', 'Proj3'
```

In that case, it seems, you don't need to have some extra settings to change module name or it's directory. You can read about it in the [official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

Comment: Thanks but I don't want these projects to be under a single one since proj2 and 3 are sort of utility/libraries and will be used in other projects. What would you do if proj3 would be needed outside of rootproject?

Comment: Then you have to publish it's artifact into some local repository and use it the same as other dependencies

Comment: That will work. Is how to do this explained in the user guide? Or can you demonstrate?

Comment: Yes, user guide has some topics about this, for example this one https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html but note, that if you have an older Gradle version, you have to look the docs for your version, because AFAIK it was changed in 3.x. Some more example can be found on SO too

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it without needing to publish anything or changing the directory structure.

Project 3 does not need a `settings.gradle` or dependencies in it `build.gradle`.

Project 2 needs `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':Proj3'
project(':Proj3').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Proj3')
```

and `build,gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Proj3')
}
```

Project 1 needs `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':Proj3', ':Proj2'
project(':Proj3').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Proj3')
project(':Proj2').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Proj2')
```

and `build,gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Proj2')
}
```

And that's the key! Project 1 while only depending on Project 2 needs to include and specify project 3 also in its settings. Then all works fine.

Comment: This is what I want to do (except I don't want to include proj3 twice, shouldn't the build tool handle mutlilevel dependencies?). Anyhow, it says the equivalent of "Project with path ':Proj3' could not be found in project ':Proj2'" at the compile (or implementation) dependency when I try. As an aside, I don't understand why something like this is so difficult in gradle/maven..